# /film/film/runtime always returns null

Tags: freebase

Whenever I try to query for the length of a film I get lists of null. The query I use is directly from the "Build query" button on their site and looks like this:

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/film/film",
  "/film/film/runtime": []
}]
```

Ufortunately all the responses I get look like this:

```
{
 "name": "4D Man",
  "type": "/film/film",
  "/film/film/runtime": [
    null
  ],
  "id": "/en/4d_man"
}
```

I can hover over the links you can see on the query page and see the runtime (in this case 85 minutes) but as you can see all I get from the query is null. This may be a Freebase bug, but any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a single runtime of a film, the same film can have different runtimes (original version, director's cut, etc...) Freebase use the [film_cut type](http://www.freebase.com/film/film_cut?schema=) to contain the different runtimes of a movie

You can use this query to get the runtimes:

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "/film/film/runtime": [{
    "runtime": null
  }]
}]
```

Tune this query to your needs, you may need type_of_film_cut or film_release_region.